# How to update JavaScript with a value from web.config file in an ASP.NET MVC4 Razor project?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to use a web.config setting such as "serverPath" below in a JavaScript file in an ASP.NET MVC4 Razor project?

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="serverPath" value="http://myserver" />
</appSettings>
```

I would like to change the URL of the following jQuery ajax call depending upon debug or release mode

```
  var request = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://myserver/api/cases',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json'
  });
```

Is is possible to read the value from web.config like a View and substitute it in the .js file?

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative is to have a js file that contains your configuration in the way that the web.config does for a .net web site:

`configuration.js`:

```
var configuration = {
    apiurl: 'http://myserver/api/',
    someOtherSetting: 'my-value'
};
```

Well, you could either write this configuration into your page as javascript or link to the script or merge and minify into a common file.  It would become part of your deployment process.

Then use it as you would any js object:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: configuration.apiurl,
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Or some variant thereof.

Comment: While this would work I would prefer to centralize all my config information in the web.config file which has the capability to automatically have different configurations for debug and release modes.

Comment: To allow for choosing a different version for different configuration modes (debug/release/etc) you could have a web.config setting of "configurationFileName" and switch between configuration.debug.js and configuraiton.release.js as the value of the appSetting. Then use the value to dynamically choose the path of the static JS file.

Comment: That is certainly an option @Arkaine55.  For our automated build scenario we have the templates configured to produce the correct configuration file.  It *does* make sense to somehow get to different versions of the file though :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use this in your view:

```
@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serverPath"]
```

For passing through to an external js file you need your function to have a parameter and call it via your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    getData('@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serverPath"]');
</script>
```

When your js file has something like this:

```
function getData(path) {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: path,
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    return request;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would read the value in the controller:

```
var serverPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("serverPath");
```

Then set the view model's property with that value

```
myViewModel.ServerPath = serverPath;
return View(myViewModel);
```

And in the view simply feed it into JS:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: '@(Model.ServerPath)',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json'
  });
```

Comment: This is a stand-alone JavaScript file which is linked into the View so the JavaScript is not in the view. I don't think there is a Modle accessible in the .js file, but I'm not certain.

Comment: In that case, you'll use Linus' approach and pass it into a method that is in your JS file: 
<script type="text/javascript">
    getData('@Model.ServerPath');
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: '@(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serverPath"])',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json'
  });
```

Comment: Because the JavaScript is in a separate .js file that is linked into the view it does not appear this works. The @ConfigurationManager... is still in the rendered page.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that for ASP.NET MVC4 Razor this way:

```
@{
    var apiBaseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ApiBaseUrl");
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var request = $.ajax({
          url: '@apiBaseUrl/cases',
          type: 'GET',
          cache: false,
          dataType: 'json'
      });

    });
</script>
```